# How does the intravenous administration of cholecystokinin provoke panic attacks?

Tags: neuroscience, emotion, neuroanatomy

**Background**

I recently read a paper [(The James-Lange theory of emotions: a critical examination and an alternative theory](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1415404?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)), in which the [James-Lange Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James%E2%80%93Lange_theory) was challenged by [Walter Bradford Cannon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walter_Bradford_Cannon).

Hence it was stated that:

> {Emotional responses can be distinguished by on the basis of autonomic activity., emotions were less intense when the brain was disconnected from the viscera} ... Some artificial manipulations of organ activity can induce emotions such as *intravenous administration of of cholecystokinin (a gastric peptide) which can provoke panic attacks*.

**Question**

What is the physiological process of intravenously inducing an emotion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emotions are often linked to chemical activity in the brain. Neurotransmitters such as serotonin , dopamine, norepinephrine etc are linked to inducing emotional states, therefore if you can take a drug which will increase the amount of a transmitter then you will respond accordingly e.g. MDMA > serotonin > feeling of escstacy/happiness (Meyer & Quenzer, 2013).

In the case of Cholecystokinin (CCK), Singh et al found evidence suggesting that activation of the brain CCK-B receptor induces anxiety and that selective antagonists of this receptor represent a separate class of anxiolytic (relaxing) agents.

Simply:

- Inject drug
- drug reaches blood brain barrier
- drug crosses or is turned into drug that can cross (e.g. codiene > morphine)
- drug turns into neurotransmitter/ or precursor to (e.g. 5HTP > serotonin)
- binds to/ activates receptor this activation causes an emotional/physical
  response

This process varies depending on the drug but that is loosely it as I understand it. Much of this taken from the Meyers textbook, which I read a long time ago so feel free to correct me.

[Singh, L., Lewis, A. S., Field, M. J., Hughes, J., & Woodruff, G. N. (1991). Evidence for an involvement of the brain cholecystokinin B receptor in anxiety. Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences, 88(4), 1130-1133.](http://www.pnas.org/content/88/4/1130.full.pdf)

Meyer, J. S., & Quenzer, L. F. (2013). Psychopharmacology: Drugs, the brain, and behavior.

Comment: Perfect, that is exactly the kind of answer that I was looking for!

Comment: "binds to/ activates receptor this activation causes an emotional/physical response"  <-- this part is a little vague ;)

Comment: haha yeah I guess could add more detail but I think simplification is ok here?